# Inital letter of chapter title as title background with KOMA-Script

Tags: koma-script, chapters

I’m trying to recreate the following style for chapter titles for `scrbook`.

[image]

I tried to implement this by redefining `\chapterlinesformat` and using the package `xstring` to extract the first character of the chapter title.
I managed to cobble together the code below, but it gives the following error:

```
mwe.tex|22 error| Missing number, treated as zero.
```

If one replaces `#3` in `\firstchar{#3}` by an explicit text, then the code works and gives the desired result.
I suspect that the command `\firstchar` doesn’t work because the argument `#3` of `\chapterlinesformat` is already formatted.
But I don’t know how to circumvent this problem, or how to approach the task differently.

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}

% getting the first character of a string using xparse
\newcommand{\firstchar}[1]{\StrChar{#1}{1}}

\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \makebox(0,20)[l]{%
      \hspace{-20pt}%
      \fontsize{60}{6}%
      \selectfont%
      \color{black!15!white}%
      \firstchar{#3}%
    }%
  #3
}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Digital Services of the University}

Here is some text.

\end{document}
```

The output if one replaces `\firstchar{#3}` by `\firstchar{Digital Services of the University}`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you insert `\showtokens{#3}` at the beginning of your redefined `\chapterlinesformat`, you'll see this on the terminal and in the log file:

```latex
> \interlinepenalty \@M Digital Services of the University\@@par .
\chapterlinesformat #1#2#3->\showtokens {#3}
                                            \myExtractFirstLetter {#3}\makeb...l.32 \chapter*{Digital Services of the University}
```

So, your `#3` does not start with the first letter of the title because KOMA-Script inserted a very high `\interlinepenalty` (10000) to make sure the title can't be broken between two pages without your explicit consent.

## Robust method

Simplest setup without `hyperref` nor `nameref`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % for the non-ASCII demo title
\usepackage{lmodern}            % can be arbitrarily scaled
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@my@extract@first@char#1\MyFirstChar#2#3\my@endTitle{#2}

\newcommand{\myExtractFirstChar}[2]{%
  \edef#2{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@my@extract@first@char #1\my@endTitle}}%
}

\let\MyFirstChar\@firstofone
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \myExtractFirstChar{#3}{\MyExtractedFirstChar}%
  \makebox(0,20)[l]{%
      \hspace{-20pt}%
      \fontsize{60}{6}\selectfont
      \color{black!15!white}%
      \MyExtractedFirstChar
    }%
  #3% <--------- don't forget!
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{\MyFirstChar{Œ}uvres complètes}

Here is some text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use `hyperref` or `nameref`, it is not strictly necessary but might be nicer, for some applications, to explicitly tell `gettitlestring` that the `\MyFirstChar` command in titles does not matter:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % for the non-ASCII demo title
\usepackage{lmodern}            % can be arbitrarily scaled
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[expand]{gettitlestring}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@my@extract@first@char#1\MyFirstChar#2#3\my@endTitle{#2}

\newcommand{\myExtractFirstChar}[2]{%
  \edef#2{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@my@extract@first@char #1\my@endTitle}}%
}

\let\MyFirstChar\@firstofone
\GetTitleStringDisableCommands{\let\MyFirstChar\@firstofone}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \myExtractFirstChar{#3}{\MyExtractedFirstChar}%
  \makebox(0,20)[l]{%
      \hspace{-20pt}%
      \fontsize{60}{6}\selectfont
      \color{black!15!white}%
      \MyExtractedFirstChar
    }%
  #3% <--------- don't forget!
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{\MyFirstChar{Œ}uvres complètes\label{chap}}

Here is some text. The chapter title is ``\nameref{chap}.''

% You need \usepackage{refcount} in order to test this.
%
% \edef\zzz{\unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
%   \getrefbykeydefault{chap}{name}{dflt}}}%
% \show\zzz % > \zzz=macro:->Œuvres complètes.

\end{document}
```

The left side shows the PDF bookmark:

[image]

## More automatic but less robust solution

Another, however less robust way to solve the problem, consists in using a simple regular expression in order to find the first letter in `\chapterlinesformat`'s third argument. The command `\myExtractFirstLetter`, defined below, assigns its second argument locally, but this could easily be made global if you prefer.

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}            % can be arbitrarily scaled
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__jendrik_match_seq

% The second argument must be a macro or expl3 token list variable
\NewDocumentCommand \myExtractFirstLetter { m m }
  {
    % The (?i) makes the [a-z] class case-insensitive
    \regex_extract_once:nnNTF { (?i)[a-z] } {#1} \l__jendrik_match_seq
      { \seq_get_left:NN \l__jendrik_match_seq #2 }
      { \tl_clear:N #2 }        % no match -> clear the #2 macro / tl var
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \myExtractFirstLetter{#3}{\myFirstLetter}%
  \makebox(0,20)[l]{%
      \hspace{-20pt}%
      \fontsize{60}{6}\selectfont
      \color{black!15!white}%
      \myFirstLetter
    }%
  #3% <--------- don't forget!
}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Digital Services of the University}

Here is some text.

\end{document}
```

[image]